# I am getting a wrong content assist in RPGLE program in visual studio. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg, ibm-ifs

[RPGLE program in Vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsQCb.png)

I have enabled all the required extensions in vs code for RPGLE language support. Extension "RPGLE language tools" is supposed to show content assist for fully free format programs but it is showing me something else.

Answer (score 0):

Maintainer here! What is the 'wrong' content assist? What are you expecting to see after `Dcl-S`?

Comment: Hello Sir, after typing Dcl-s, I expect a popup(suggestion dropdown) to tell me that I need to enter a variable name now and then the variable type(Char/int/zoned etc). Followed by variable type, braces and length. It is something that happens for an opcode. Instead, I get the suggestions shown in the attached photos which I am not sure are correct or not. 
PS -  I am from a COBOL background and new to RPG, so I may be missing something here.

Comment: Right now, the content assist does not make those kinds of suggestions. It currently just parses for definitions and makes definition suggestions as you write code.